# How to handle Response object in React from Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I've read through numerous answers on SO, but most don't show both the Flask and JS side of my question, so I don't believe this is a duplicate. Specifically, using React/JS, I'm attempting to fetch a list of dictionaries from my Flask API.

On the server side, I've successfully serialized my class, and can print the list of dictionaries as expected. However, after I return it using JSONIFY (as suggested in several SO questions), it results in undefined on the JS side when I try to access the data. From reading online, it appeared that I could attempt to JSON parse the response data, but this similarly shows undefined. This leads me to believe that the issue may in fact be on the server side. Regardless, I'm also unsure how to properly access this list of dictionaries in my fetch function (I would've expected that I can do something along the lines of data[0]['name']).

I'd really appreciate any guidance you might have - thank you for reading this far.

eqtls prints as follows in api.py:

[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Bearbrook Skateboard Park', 'description': 'Flat asphalt surface, 5 components', 'xcoord': -75, 'ycoord': 45, 'date_added': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 26, 19, 46, 10)}]

api.py

```
class Activity(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    xcoord = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    ycoord = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
    description = db.Column(db.String(200))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    #create a string
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<id={self.id}, name={self.name},description={self.description},xcoord={self.xcoord},ycoord={self.ycoord},date_added={self.date_added}>"

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id, 
            'name': self.name,
            'description': self.description,
            'xcoord': self.xcoord, 
            'ycoord': self.ycoord,
            'date_added': self.date_added
        }


@app.route('/allActivities', methods=['GET'])
def allActivities():
    print('hit allActivities routing')
    allActivities = Activity.query.all()
    print(str(allActivities))
    eqtls=[activity.serialize() for activity in allActivities]
    print(str(eqtls))

    
    sys.stdout.flush()

    return jsonify(eqtls)
```

Currently in app.js, my data variable logs as undefined.
app.js

```
useEffect(()=> {
       fetch('/allActivities').then(response => {
       if(response.ok){
           console.log(response)
         return response.json()
       }
       }).then(data => setAllActivities(data))
           .then(data => {
               console.log(data);
               //var jsonData = JSON.parse((data));
               //console.log(jsonData[0].name);
           })

   },[])
```

Comment: What does `response` log? What is the response value in the network tab? Is it what you are expecting on the client side?

Comment: Thanks for the response Drew. The actual response object shows up in console with a status of 200 / OK and indicates a successful GET. However, the actual data is undefined and doesn't reflect the list/dictionary structure I can print on the server, so I'd say the client side behavior isn't in line with my expectations.

Comment: @demongman Successive then blocks return the return value of the previous one. So the third one returns the value that setAllActivities delivers in the second call, and that is undefined. It may help you to check the network tab of the developer tools to see if the result is as expected. Your output in the last call to then will definitely return undefined, even though the correct value was passed to setAllActivities.

Comment: @Detlef - sorry for the late response - and thank you so much for your comment. This actually ended up being it - essentially in my original series of three 'then' blocks, I overwrote with undefined. Apologies for the basic question & thank you so much!